# Swap elements attribute-values in XML (WSDL) file?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

Consider I’ve got any standard WSDL file (represented in XML):

```
<wsdl:definitions>

      <wsdl:types>
        ...
      </wsdl:types>

      <wsdl:message>
        ...
      </wsdl:message>

      <wsdl:portType name="countrySoap”>
         <wsdl:operation name="GetCountryByCountryCode">
             <wsdl:documentation>Get country name by country code</wsdl:documentation>
             <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapIn" />
             <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapOut" />
         </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetISD">
            <wsdl:documentation>Get International Dialing Code </wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:GetISDSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:GetISDSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        ...
      <wsdl:portType name="countrySoap”>

  ....
</wsdl:definitions>
```

What I would like to do is have a simple/efficient way of swapping the input and output messages for every message.

So for instance, I want:

```
         <wsdl:operation name="GetCountryByCountryCode">
             <wsdl:documentation>Get country name by country code</wsdl:documentation>
             <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapOut" />
             <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapIn" />
         </wsdl:operation>
```

The example wsdl file I’ve been working with can be found here:
    http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL

**Further notes:**

- I am probably look for an XSLT-based solution, because this would seem to me to be the more efficient. For instance, my current solution is Java-based, but it does not seem as efficient as I would like.
- It would be good if a solution could be capable of ignoring any namespace, for example: some wsdl files present as: `wsdl:definitions`, `wsdl:portType`, `wsdl:operation` - while others might just be `definitions`, `portType`, `operation`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT (both 1.0 and 2.0) transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="some:wsdl">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:input/@message">
  <xsl:attribute name="message">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../x:output/@message"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:output/@message">
  <xsl:attribute name="message">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../x:input/@message"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (obtained from the provided, severely malformed one):

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="some:wsdl">

          <wsdl:types>
            ...
          </wsdl:types>

          <wsdl:message>
            ...
          </wsdl:message>

          <wsdl:portType name="countrySoap">
             <wsdl:operation name="GetCountryByCountryCode">
                 <wsdl:documentation>Get country name by country code</wsdl:documentation>
                 <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapIn" />
                 <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapOut" />
             </wsdl:operation>
            <wsdl:operation name="GetISD">
                <wsdl:documentation>Get International Dialing Code </wsdl:documentation>
                <wsdl:input message="tns:GetISDSoapIn" />
                <wsdl:output message="tns:GetISDSoapOut" />
            </wsdl:operation>
            ...
          </wsdl:portType>

      ....
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="some:wsdl">
   <wsdl:types>
            ...
          </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message>
            ...
          </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="countrySoap">
      <wsdl:operation name="GetCountryByCountryCode">
         <wsdl:documentation>Get country name by country code</wsdl:documentation>
         <wsdl:input message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapOut"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:GetCountryByCountryCodeSoapIn"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="GetISD">
         <wsdl:documentation>Get International Dialing Code </wsdl:documentation>
         <wsdl:input message="tns:GetISDSoapOut"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:GetISDSoapIn"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
            ...
          </wsdl:portType>

      ....
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, but could we add something to take care of situations when a particular wsdl file may not contain any namespace prefixes. For example, this is a sample one I’ve been working with http://ws.xwebservices.com/XWebBlog/V2/XWebBlog.wsdl, there are of course others. thnx.

Comment: @Larry: This same transformation works OK with the linked-to XML document. You need to read a little bit about namespaces. In the linked-to XML document, the names are unprefixed, but they are stil in a namespace (the default namespace). They are selected by `x:ElementName`, where the prefix `x:` is bound to the default namespace. Just search for "Xpath default namespace" and you will find multitude of questions (this is the most FAQ in XPath and XSLT) and many good answers -- so you will understand this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about the namespace prefix, it doesn't really matter as long as the namespace uri matches.

Both XSLT and XQuery can give you a compact solution. The output indentation might be a little easier to tweak in XSLT though.

Here an XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wsdl:input">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../wsdl:output/(@*|node())"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wsdl:output">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../wsdl:input/(@*|node())"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here an XQuery 1.0 solution:

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare namespace wsdl = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/";

declare function local:recurse-nodes($nodes) {
    for $node in $nodes
    return typeswitch ($node)
        case $node as element (wsdl:input) return
            element { node-name($node) } { $node/../wsdl:output/local:recurse-nodes(@*|node()) }
        case $node as element (wsdl:output) return
            element { node-name($node) } { $node/../wsdl:input/local:recurse-nodes(@*|node()) }
        case $node as element () return
            element { node-name($node) } { $node/local:recurse-nodes(@*|node()) }
        case $node as document-node () return
            document { local:recurse-nodes($node/node()) }
        default return $node
};

local:recurse-nodes(doc("country.xml"))
```

HTH!